# zabbixの送信元メールアドレスは、実在しないアドレスを使用できますか。

Tags: postfix, sendmail, zabbix

zabbixのイベント通知メールにおいて、実在しないアドレスを使用できますか。

zabbixの初期設定のアドレス（zabbix@example.com）だと、SMTPサーバーではじかれるような動きをします。

zabbixイベントから確認できるアクションのエラー：
wrong answer on RCPT TO "554 5.7.1 zabbix@example.com: Sender address rejected: Access denied"

また、zabbixサーバー(Linux)にはメールを送信するための構築はしていません。

自身のアドレス to 自身のアドレス　であればメールを発砲できるのですが、
zabbixサーバー内でメールを送信するためにpostfixやsendmailをインストールしたり設定が必要だったりしますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実在しないメールアドレスを使って、設定時のテスト送信がOKになるかどうかはZabbixで指定するSMTPサーバー次第です。

通常、本番で運用されているSMTPサーバーでは送信元メールアドレスの実在性について次のようなチェックを行っている場合があります。

- 内部(ローカルネットワーク)から送信されたメール
  送信元メールアドレスのドメインが管理しているドメインか？
  送信元メールアドレスのユーザーは存在しているユーザーか？
- 外部(インターネット)から送信されたメール
  送信元メールアドレスのドメインのメールを受信できるサーバーが存在するか？(MXレコードやAレコードの有無、場合によってはサーバーへの接続)

ただ、これらは必ずしも設定しているわけではなく、一部のみチェックする、または、全くチェックをしない場合もあります。つまり、実在しないメールアドレスであっても受け付けるSMTPサーバーもあるということです。ということで、そのようなSMTPサーバーを指定すればZabbixで設定自体はできます。同じサーバーのPostfixだとうまくいく場合があるのは、ローカルホストからのメールは送信元メールアドレスをチェックしないように設定しているからに過ぎません。つまり、送信元をチェックせずに受け付けてくれるSMTPサーバーが他に存在しない場合は、そのようなSMTPサーバーを作るか、同じサーバーにPostfixを入れるしか無いと言うことです。

さて、「設定できる」と「実際に送られる」は違うことに注意が必要です。Zabbixのメール送信テストでZabbixがわかるのは、SMTPサーバーまではメールが送られたということだけです。SMTPサーバーが宛先の最終配送先でなければ、宛先のメールボックスまで送られたかどうかはわかりません。実在しないメールアドレスを送信元に用いた場合、送られない可能性があります。送信元メールアドレスのドメインが存在しないとメールの受信を拒否する場合があるからです。そして、この場合、拒否されたメールは送信元へエラーメールを返ろうとするのですが、そもそも送信元メールアドレスは存在しないので、どこにも送られないことになります(エラーメールが送れなかったエラーメールがMAILER-DAEMONに送られますが、確認できるのはサーバーの管理者のみです)。

もしかしたら、全くデタラメなアドレスでもうまくいくかも知れません。ただ、送信元を実在しないメールアドレスを使った場合は、メールが正しく送信できない可能性が常につきまとうことを意識してください。なるべくトラブル無くメールを送信したいのであれば、ちゃんと受信ができるメールアドレスを送信元として使用することを推奨します。